# Black screen while opening Godot game's apk

Tags: android, 3d, godot

Hello everyone I have created a 3d game using godot game engine many people have played it and it runs well in their device but when some people open my game it shows black screen(In their android device).Can anyone tell me any fix for that please.

I have tried the game even on a 3gb ram device but I don't know some 4gb ram device are even unable to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Godot renders with GLES3 it will use some features that are not supported in every device.

If there is a significant portion of users with this problem, you can try enabling GLES2 fallback, or switching to GLES2 entirely. Know that this will disable some effects.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I will surely look forward for it well you can check out my game on YouTube Name of the game is Drocomon let's go Godot and my channel name is Tech Shubham Official

Answer (score 1):

After a long period of development, the Godot 4.2 mono version finally supports exporting for mobile devices using .NET 8, and I wanted to give it a try. However, after upgrading the project from 4.1 to 4.2 and exporting it to my Android phone, I encountered several issues:

- The loading time is excessively long.
- Only the GUI is visible.
- The world turns back.
- The performance is severely laggy.

Despite attempting various solutions, only one proved to work:
Open Project Settings -> Rendering -> Renderer:

1. Change `Rendering Method` to `gl_compatibility`.
2. Change `Rendering Method.mobile` to `gl_compatibility`.
3. Reload the project and export it again.